# AS3: How to stop a movieclip using Class?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, timeline

I'm doing a space shooter game, and I want my ship to stop shaking when the game is over.

I created a class called **Main.as**, and I added the ship as child object.

Inside the **spaceship_mc** movieclip I made a motion tween (**which is the shake I want to stop**).

*This is the order: **spaceship_mc** > **spaceship_motion** (symbol used for motion tween).*

**Class struncture**

```
    public class Main extends Sprite {
    private var spaceship:spaceship_mc; ...

          public function Main() {
        placeSpaceship(); ...
```

**Game Over**

```
private function die():void {
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnterFrm);
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onMouseCk);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description you just need to call stop() on the ship MovieClip.

`spaceship.stop()` or `spaceship.gotoAndStop(1)`